# Calling function in factory from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a factory that makes a http get request to an api my classmates and I have created. For some reason my controller that accepts the submission from a form for the parameters of our request is returning: 
`angular.js:9101 TypeError: Cannot read property 'crawlWeb' of undefined`

The intention is to use another controller to manipulate the data elsewhere. I've tried looking in several places and found similar examples but still seem to have the same error.
[AngularJS: Cannot call function in factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079457/angularjs-cannot-call-function-in-factory)
https://github.com/amitavroy/learningci/blob/06_angularjs_factory_02/js/singlepage/singlepage_module.js

There seems to be something wrong with my factory setup that isn't allowing my controllers to access its members.

Factory:

```js
myApp.factory('SharedData', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
  var requestReturn = {};

  requestReturn.result = function(p) {
      return $http({
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www.form-urlencoded'},
        url: 'http://www.capstone-crawler.appspot.com/crawler',
        method: 'GET',
        params: p,
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        requestReturn = response;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('theReturn', response);
      })
    }
}]);
```

Controller:

```js
myApp.controller('FetchController', ['$scope', function($scope, SharedData) {
    
  $scope.setParams = function(tosend) {
    
    var toSubmit = {
      pages:    $scope.tosend.pagesToCrawl,   
      depth:    $scope.tosend.crawlDepth,
      start:    $scope.tosend.webCrawlURL,
      keyword:  $scope.tosend.keyWord
    }
    console.log(toSubmit);
    SharedData.crawlWeb(toSubmit);
  }
}]);
```

Comment: you need to `return` something from factory otherwise use `services`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning from `Factory` service.You need to return `requestReturn` object to use the `SharedData` service.

Also there is no `crawlWeb` function in the `SharedData` factory.

```
myApp.factory('SharedData', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
      var requestReturn = {};

      requestReturn.result = function(p) {
          // Rest of code
        },

      requestReturn.crawlWeb=function(){
      alert("service Called");
       }
       return requestReturn;

    }]);
```

Please see this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yy2pu6wz/).

Here I am calling the SharedData.crawlWeb on click of button